# Save Form Select List Scrollbar State

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way I can save form select list scrollbar state? I need it to save scrollbar state (position) with JavaScript, JQuery or Ajax.

Any help.

Comment: what is `form select list scrollbar state`?

Comment: Its position of scrollbar part which you move ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of such a value.

You can convert your select to a widget and then you can save all states

A quick google gives me this http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/
Not that it is the greatest I have seen, but it gives you an idea

jQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dropdownReplacement

Comment: I need to save scrollbar position it self not the item.

Comment: @EMC I know. I understand. Only way I can think of is to replace the select with a widget where you DO have access to the select scroll position